# Using articles with position titles

Tags: articles

Please, could you clarify for me is it necessary to put an article (whether indefinite or definite) before a title of someone's position, job title, etc?

For example in context of official documents or articles:

> *(The/a)* CIO needs to sign for implement a procedure.
>
> The service check is performed by *(the/a)* Head of Security on a
>   monthly basis.
>
> The central hospital examination needs to be initiated by *(the/a)*
>   Minister of Healthcare.

All articles I've found regarding this question are very ambiguous. So I just wonder is there any rule for such case.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to the person who holds a particular title, or to that position itself in the context of a single company, use **the** for positions which normally are held by a single person, such as CIO, or **a** if the position can be held by more than one, such as Assistant Vice President.

> We'll have to run that by the CFO.
>
> Expenditures over $10K require authorization from an Assistant Vice President.

If you're referring to a group of such individuals meeting for a conference, say, then it gets a little more complicated:

> The conference was attended by **banking industry CIOs**. **The CIOs** attending the meeting unanimously supported legislation to increase the minimum prison sentence for theft involving hacks into a computer system. **A CIO** from New York, who wished to remain anonymous, suggested that a person convicted of such a felony should be placed in solitary confinement without access to the internet.